# Code using large memory to display images?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox, viewer

I am making a simple image viewer and editor using Winforms and C#,but am facing a problem that i think may be in this function ;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts image details from specified image file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="BitmapName">The name of file to process.</param>
    /// <param name="ImageName">The TextBox to recieve image name.</param>
    /// <param name="ImageCreated">The TextBox to recieve image creation date.</param>
    /// <param name="Size">The TextBox to recieve image size.</param>
    /// <param name="Width">The TextBox to recieve image width.</param>
    /// <param name="Height">The TextBox to recieve image height.</param>
    /// <param name="HResolution">The TextBox to recieve image's Horizontal Resolution.</param>
    /// <param name="VResolution">The TextBox to recieve image's Vertical Resolution.</param>
    /// <param name="Type">The TextBox to recieve the type of image.</param>
    /// <param name="Preview">The PictuteBox to display this image as a preview.</param>
    public void GetImageData(string BitmapName, TextBox ImageName, TextBox ImageCreated, TextBox Size, TextBox Width, TextBox Height, TextBox HResolution, TextBox VResolution, TextBox Type, PictureBox Preview)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(BitmapName);
            ImageName.Text = fileinfo.Name;
            ImageCreated.Text = fileinfo.CreationTime.ToString();
            Size.Text = (fileinfo.Length / 1024).ToString() + " Kilobytes";
            Image image = Image.FromFile(BitmapName);
            Bitmap Bit = new Bitmap(image);
            Height.Text = Bit.Height.ToString() + " px";
            Width.Text = Bit.Width.ToString() + " px";
            HResolution.Text = Bit.HorizontalResolution.ToString() + " dpi";
            VResolution.Text = Bit.VerticalResolution.ToString() + " dpi";
            if (fileinfo.Extension == ".bmp" || fileinfo.Extension == ".BMP")
            {
                Type.Text = "Bitmap Image";
            }
            else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".jpeg" || fileinfo.Extension == ".JPEG")
            {
                Type.Text = "Jpeg Image";
            }
            else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".jpg" || fileinfo.Extension == ".JPG")
            {
                Type.Text = "Jpg Image";
            }
            else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".png" || fileinfo.Extension == ".PNG")
            {
                Type.Text = "Png Image";
            }
            else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".gif" || fileinfo.Extension == ".GIF")
            {
                Type.Text = "GIF Image";
            }
            Preview.Image = image;
            Bit.Dispose();
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            Preview.Image = Properties.Resources.InvalidImage;
        }
    }
```

,this function extracts image details using Bitmap class but after viewing 20-30 images it uses almost 600-700 MB RAM.Please tell where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't dispose Preview.Image before changing it, Try this:

```
 public void GetImageData(string BitmapName, TextBox ImageName, TextBox ImageCreated, TextBox Size, TextBox Width, TextBox Height, TextBox HResolution, TextBox VResolution, TextBox Type, PictureBox Preview)
    {
      try
      {
        FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(BitmapName);
        ImageName.Text = fileinfo.Name;
        ImageCreated.Text = fileinfo.CreationTime.ToString();
        Size.Text = (fileinfo.Length / 1024).ToString() + " Kilobytes";
        Image image = Image.FromFile(BitmapName);
        using (Bitmap Bit = new Bitmap(image))
        {
          Height.Text = Bit.Height.ToString() + " px";
          Width.Text = Bit.Width.ToString() + " px";
          HResolution.Text = Bit.HorizontalResolution.ToString() + " dpi";
          VResolution.Text = Bit.VerticalResolution.ToString() + " dpi";
          if (fileinfo.Extension == ".bmp" || fileinfo.Extension == ".BMP")
          {
            Type.Text = "Bitmap Image";
          }
          else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".jpeg" || fileinfo.Extension == ".JPEG")
          {
            Type.Text = "Jpeg Image";
          }
          else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".jpg" || fileinfo.Extension == ".JPG")
          {
            Type.Text = "Jpg Image";
          }
          else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".png" || fileinfo.Extension == ".PNG")
          {
            Type.Text = "Png Image";
          }
          else if (fileinfo.Extension == ".gif" || fileinfo.Extension == ".GIF")
          {
            Type.Text = "GIF Image";
          }
          if (Preview.Image != null)
            Preview.Image.Dispose();
          Preview.Image = image;
        }
      }
      catch (OutOfMemoryException)
      {
        Preview.Image = Properties.Resources.InvalidImage;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This might be the solution but you also want to use a memory profiler to really make sure. You are dealing with images and therefore you have to watch out for these things. Memory profilers are really easy to use and they show you lots of room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

you don't dispose image, only the bitmap use

```
bit = new Bitmap(filename);
```

to load image ad bitmap.